# #define as unsigned char

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, unsigned-char

I would like to know how can I tell to compiler that a `#define` is an **unsigned char**.

```
#define SET_BITS_LOW 0x80
```

Here `SET_BITS_LOW` is, *by default*, an **int** but I want an **unsigned char**

Comment: `#define SET_BITS_LOW ((unsigned char)0x80)`?

Comment: It will be promoted to `int` in most contexts anyway.

Comment: @rmartinjak Can you explain it please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
#define SET_BITS_LOW  ((unsigned char)0x80)
```

Comment: You will get a compilation warning of: conversion to 'unsigned char' from 'int' may alter its value